# Dailymotion Flash Player API

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dailymotion-api

Dailymotion Flash API has been discontinued. It redirects to use new Player API.
Old Flash API: http://www.dailymotion.com/pl/doc/api/player-deprecated/flash_api
New Player API: http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/player.html
Old API is still working correctly. There is no information how long it will be available yet.
I tried to update Flash project with new Player API. Everything would be fine, but when I try to load new Player API under other Flash project, it tells that loaded dailymotion player api is not pure Flash file that can be run.
Old dailymotion api code:

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.dailymotion.com/swf?enableApi=1&chromeless=1"));
```

Old dailymotion api result: working.
New player api code:

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xjk5h2?chromeless=1&controls=flash&startscreen=flash&html=0&api=location"));
```

New player api result:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type.
```

How can I load new player api under other Flash project? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Our documentation isn't clear. We'll clarify all these points : support period, version, usage, etc.

I recommend you to use the /swf route into your as3 projects. The /embed/video is just a wrapper around /swf. You'll still benefit of last improvements using that route (/swf).

Hope this help.

Yvan